# Is it possible to calculate an average number without a finite set of numbers?

Tags: statistics, average

```
Starting At 12:00:00  I have 0 items
         At 12:00:10  I have 488 items
         At 12:00:20  I have 971 items
         At 12:00:30  I have 1532 items
         At 12:00:40  I have 2103 items
```

More items are added continuously and reported every 10 seconds. Is it possible to calculate the average number of items per minute, second and hour when the number of items may never stop accumulating?

Comment: If you mean theoretically - then yes, just look at s(n)/n where s(n) is the nth partial sum. Look at its limit as n goes to infinity. If you mean in practice, for data that is coming in, then the recurrence s = a*s + (1-a)*m where m is the measurement, s is the previous mean, and a is a number between 0 and 1, will give a form of simple running average. Linear systems theory has much more about this. Is that what you are looking for? (Not every sequence has a mean, though).

Comment: @PonderStibbons I'll try to work with the formula you listed. I'm writing a computer program and wanted to see if it would be possible to get an average of values without having all of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a programming context with a function input() that is called to get each successive reading from some external source, then mean = w * input() + (1-w)*mean will compute a running mean of the input values. Where w is a weight between 0 and 1. When w=1, the mean is set to the immediate value of the input. For w=0 it remains unchanged at its initial value. For w=0.5, for example, it will be an exponentially weighted mean of the previous values in the sequence.

If you literally need the unweighted arithmetic mean then you need to keep a counter:

```
c=1
m=input()

repeat:
  m = c * m + input()
  c = c + 1
  m = m/c
```

This is really just a way of keeping the sum of all the inputs and the count of all the inputs, and noting that the ratio is the mean. The method above has more operations, but keeps the stored values from drifting in a typical context.

Floating point error would typically take its toll of course.